# How to use vue 3 with nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt3 for a project and when installing it with the cli in the docs it generated a vue 2.7 project.

How can I get to use vue 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Vue3, you'll need to follow CLI's instructions for Nuxt3 located here: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction

If you want to use some Vue-specific packages, here you are: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins/#vue-plugins

Comment: the first link is dead do you have an alternative ?

Comment: @yasseros I've updated it.